How to find out which API to use in ARM Template to provision Postgresql flexible server
I created a bicep script to provision out a Postgresql Flexible server. I then build the script and output an ARM template to use in Azure Portal.
The deployment fails with the following errors.
No registered resource provider found for location 'eastus' and API version '2024-03-01-preview' for type 'flexibleServers

Then it goes on to list out the supported APis and regions.
Is there a way to find out the latest API for a specific region and a particular resource supports before trying to deploy?
Update
I attempted to create the resource from Azure portal so I can then export the template to see which API version it is using, but i am getting a Subscription 'XYZ' is not allowed to provision in region 'EastUS'. I will try to provision in another region.
Thanks

I think Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL is not registered in your subscription. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/troubleshooting/error-register-resource-provider?tabs=azure-cli#symptom

@Thomas That isn't it. It shows as registered.

@Thomas I attempted to create the resource from Azure portal so i can then export the template to see which API version it is using but I am getting a Subscription 'XYZ' is not allowed to provision in region 'EastUS'. I will just provision it in another region.

was checking the regions and east us should be ok i think: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/overview#azure-regions

No registered resource provider found for location 'eastus' and API version '2024-03-01-preview'

The error you encountered above is due to an invalid API version in the Bicep code.

You can check the supported API versions for flexibleServers.
az provider show --namespace Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL --query "resourceTypes[?resourceType=='flexibleServers'].apiVersions"


Here is the updated Bicep code to create Flexible Servers using the latest API version, 2024-08-01.
param administratorLogin string = 'Venkat'

@secure()
param administratorLoginPassword string = 'Welcome@123$'
param location string = 'eastus'
param serverName string = 'sample-server-001' // Changed to a valid server name
param serverEdition string = 'GeneralPurpose'
param skuSizeGB int = 128
param dbInstanceType string = 'Standard_D4ds_v4'
param haMode string = 'ZoneRedundant'
param availabilityZone string = '1'
param version string = '12'

resource serverName_resource 'Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/flexibleServers@2024-08-01' = {
  name: serverName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: dbInstanceType
    tier: serverEdition
  }
  properties: {
    version: version
    administratorLogin: administratorLogin
    administratorLoginPassword: administratorLoginPassword
    network: {
      publicNetworkAccess: 'Enabled' 
    }
    highAvailability: {
      mode: haMode
    }
    storage: {
      storageSizeGB: skuSizeGB
    }
    backup: {
      backupRetentionDays: 7
      geoRedundantBackup: 'Disabled'
    }
    availabilityZone: availabilityZone
  }
}

Output:

